# Using Query String in REST Web Services

Tags: web-services, rest, query-string, path-parameter

I thought one main characteristic and reason for using REST web services was to use path parameters rather than query parameters. But many publicly available REST web services use query parameters.

Am I wrong in thinking that query parameters are not supposed to be used in REST web services?
Is there a recommendation or rule about not using query parameters in REST web services?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4024271/139010

Comment: "not to use path parameters"?

Comment: Yes, the idea of RESTful uris using path parameters only is a fallacy.  A URI is simply an identifer, you can use any and all parts of it to identify a resource.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The query string can still be used in REST web services just not in the same way as normal.

You have to think of the URL as the *key* to a resource. The URL is an unique identifier for the resource. For example

```
http://example.com/products/123   -- where 123 is the id of the products.
```

Accessing to `/products` would return a full list of products. Adding the id would return a specific product.

---

#### The problem with using slashes for every filter

What if you want to order product in a specific way? Some would say

```
http://example.com/products/united-states
```

Well, now there is some ambiguity at the first look. Is united-states an id? Well that ambiguity can be solved by saying an id is represented as `\d+`. Correct.

Ok so our first parameters which is made of words is a country.

Now lets say we want to add more filters, lets try and add more slashes.

```
http://example.com/products/united-states/home/asc
```

But I don't want united states products only! But still want home products.

```
http://example.com/products/home/asc
```

Wait... is home a country? I'm not sure now, it's kind of ambiguous...
And what if I want to add another filter tomorrow? What will I do... add more slashes?

The URL becomes cluttered and full of ambiguous parameters that were optional at first and that become obligatory because of ambiguity.

---

#### My advice

The correct way, to me, would be to use the **query string** for thing specific about the query.
Because, I can sort the query in any way I want, it is still the same query. I query products.

So the form should be like

```
http://example.com/products -- all products
http://example.com/products/{id} -- specific one
http://example.com/products/?country=united-sites -- filtered
```

This way you can add new filters anytime you want and keep URLs that are clear and won't ever break even though you change the filters.

---

#### More information

If you want more information I really, really advise you to **look at [this conference](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=NEWTPFzt2-E)** by David Zülke, a guy working for the Symfony framework. He talks about a lot of things of REST web-services, but he also talk specifically about URLs, and how to build them *(Mainly from 16 to 30 minutes)*.

You can also look at **[apigee website](http://apigee.com/about/api-best-practices)**. They have a lot of videos (and books) about REST. More specifically [this video](http://apigee.com/about/api-best-practices/restful-api-design-second-edition), which is really on topic here.

Comment: /domain/products/{id} gets you into exactly the pickle rest is trying to avoid...you get ambiguous uri's which defeats the purpose of a uri pointing to a resource. To be less ambiguous, it should be something like /domain/products/id/{id}. Then if you want USA products /domain/products/country/usa. The uri is an partition scheme for partitioning your resources. The only time you would use a query string is if partitioning makes no sense.